# Simple for loop in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve http://projecteuler.net/problem=1 using Visual C# Express.

I created a Console Application and wrote the following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Euler_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (num / 3 == 0)
                    sum = sum + num;
                num++;
                System.Console.WriteLine(num);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Just to test whether I can get any output. I am not sure if this is the best method to solves this problem. The console window only opens for a second and then disappears. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably mean to be using `i` instead of `num`.

Comment: By the way, if you want N iterations of a loop, use the form for(int i=0; i < N; i++), rather than the less-than-or-equals form you've got there, which will give you 11 iterations.

Comment: Isn't `(num / 3 == 0)` the same thing as `num == 0`?  Perhaps you meant `(num % 3 == 0)`

Comment: @MikeChristensen I strongly suspect you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it using `Console.ReadKey()`. Generally, in console apps where this happens (though I'd never recommend it if you can help it... consoles tend to be run from an existing command line and are expected to exit immediately when done, back to the context of the terminal), you see something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: But where's the *Any* key?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Hardy-ha-ha - I don't see it title-cased or quoted to indicate it's a distinct thing in its own right; it literally means any given key will do the job.

Comment: @Grant It's a reference to the popular TV show "The Simpsons"

Comment: @GrantThomas, he was quoting a line from the Simpsons. He wasn't being serious.

Comment: @JasonWatkins Jeeez, I understand contemporary references, but some deserve clarification.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

after the loop

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with `ReadLine method`

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.console.readline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can either put a breakpoint on last line so the debugger will stop, add a call like ReadLine so that user input is required, add a delay (Sleep) so that the Windows stay displayed for a few seconds or run it from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

there are too much operations

```
if (i / 3 == 0)
   sum+=i;
```

And as others said,

```
 Console.ReadKey()
```

will let you see the results.

Comment: `sum++;` is *not* the same as `sum = sum + num;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the application terminates (the console closes), after your loop finishes. To keep the console open you can do one of the following:

1. If you start the application without debugger by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> instead of just <kbd>F5</kbd>, you will see a `Press any key to continue . . .` just before the program exits.
2. For me the best way to do this **using** the debugger is to add a breakpoint (<kbd>F9</kbd>) to the closing bracket of your `main` method.

Adding extra code to help you debug your program is a bad habit to me.

Comment: Only ever had code injected as in #1 in one or two 'alternative' IDEs. It's certainly not a standard in, say, Visual Studio (and to my knowledge certainly not the C# compiler); maybe you're talking about a specific application? Perhaps I'm wrong, but this is a very peculiar thing to offer without saying how to use it.

Comment: This is tested on Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F5 will leave you with a `Press any key to continue...` This will stop the console from automatically closing.

Alternatively, you can go to `Debug` in the toolbar and click `Start Without Debugging`.

This solution will prevent adding code to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here the clean code with all changes mentioned by the others. Mainly, the modulo (see %) and the Console.ReadKey

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Euler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int max = 10;
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                    sum += i;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 from 0 to {0} is: {1}", max, sum);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```